# How to draw a smile using Vision and its Face landmarks observations?

Tags: swift

I am trying to build a smile detector over a real time video (front cam) using Uibezierpath over the screen coordinates by detecting face landmarks using VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest and "Landmarks.outerlips", calculating Y offset between upper points, without using CoreML ideally - but I seem only able to get the normalised points for the landmark, where these points have their own coordinate system. I'm not sure how to convert each point to the screen coordinate system.

This answer from @Rickster seems to be in the right direction but I'm not able to fully grasp next steps:

[How to convert normalized points retrived from VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52535553/how-to-convert-normalized-points-retrived-from-vnfacelandmarkregion2d?answertab=active#tab-top)

Current output:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]